# Can someone explain this small probability contradiction?

Tags: probability, random-variables

The question is: A service organization in a large town organizes a raffle. One thousand raffle tickets are sold for $\$1$ each. Each has an equal chance of winning. First prize is $\$300$, second prize is $\$200$, and third prize is $\$100$. What is that chance of winning something?

First way: $X= \{100, 200, 300\}$, $P(X) = P(100)+ P(200)+ P(300)$ as there is one such ticket for each
=> $P(X) = 0.001 + 0.001 + 0.001 = 0.003$

Second. when the results are going to be announced, the chance for each ticket to be the first prize winner is $0.001$. to be the second prize winner the chance is, $0.999$ (not to be the first prize winner + $1/999$ (for being the second) in the same way the chance of winning the 3rd position is $998/999 \times1/998$.

=> $P(X) = 0.001 + 999/1000 \cdot 1/999 + 998/1000 + 1/998 =0.003001\dots$

Does watching the show where they announce the names of the winners increase the chance of winning? :D

Comment: No. Consider [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem)'s explanations. The probabilities stay the same all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way of calculating is more complex than needed. If you practicize it correctly then you get the same outcome:

$P\left(W_{1}\right)=\frac{1}{1000}$

$P\left(W_{2}\right)=P\left(W_{1}^{\complement}\cap W_{2}\right)=P\left(W_{1}^{\complement}\right)P\left(W_{2}\mid W_{1}^{\complement}\right)=\frac{999}{1000}\frac{1}{999}=\frac{1}{1000}$

$P\left(W_{3}\right)=P\left(W_{1}^{\complement}\cap W_{2}^{\complement}\cap W_{3}\right)=P\left(W_{1}^{\complement}\cap W_{2}^{\complement}\right)P\left(W_{3}\mid W_{1}^{\complement}\cap W_{2}^{\complement}\right)=\frac{998}{1000}\frac{1}{998}=\frac{1}{1000}$

$P\left(W_{1}\cup W_{2}\cup W_{3}\right)=P\left(W_{1}\right)+P\left(W_{2}\right)+P\left(W_{3}\right)=\frac{3}{1000}$

Here $W_i$ denotes the event of winning the $i$-th prize.

Comment: thank you very much for your thorough answer. I had forgotten to multiple the W∁1 for the third place:( 999/1000 * 998/999 * 1/998)

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be the event that you win first prize, and $S$ the event that you win second prize.  Assuming that first prize is drawn first and second prize second, it's true that $$\Pr(S|F^c)=\frac1{999},$$ but the probability of winning second prize is $$\Pr(F)\Pr(S|F)+\Pr(F^c)\Pr(S|F^c)=0+\frac{999}{1000}\frac1{999}=\frac1{1000}$$

So no, watching doesn't somehow change the probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If watching the show changed the probabilities how would you explain that watching in real time rather than with a tape delay increased the value of the ticket you bought in advance?

Related answer:
[Is this lot drawing fair?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875045/is-this-lot-drawing-fair/1875055#1875055)